# Doesn't instance call function to variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have write function to deduce how much parameters I forward to function. Something like this:

```
template<typename Arg>
constexpr size_t get_init_size(Arg arg, size_t i) {
    return i + 1;
}

template<typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr size_t get_init_size(T First_arg, Args ... args, size_t i) {
    return get_init_size(args... , i + 1);
}

auto create_ipv4_header() {
    size_t x = get_init_size(0b01, 0b10, 0b01, static_cast<size_t>(0));
    return x //<= must return 3
}
```

But compiler write:
**error: no matching function for call to 'get_init_size(int, int, int, size_t)'**
So it is problem in variadic template? And one more thing if I change variadic template to something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename ... Args>
constexpr size_t get_init_size(T First_arg, Args ... args, size_t i = 0)
```

I can put down last parameter?(I doesn't test it with variadic template) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write a recursive template function to do this, you can use the [`sizeof...()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof...) operator on the type of the parameter pack to get the number of elements directly:

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr std::size_t get_init_size(Args&&...) {
    return sizeof...(Args);
}
```

See it in action [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:46,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:46,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:46,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:46,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdlib%3E%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+...+Args%3E%0Aconstexpr+std::size_t+get_init_size(Args%26%26...)+%7B%0A++++return+sizeof...(Args)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++return+get_init_size(1,+3.51,+%22test%22)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:58.92351274787535,l:%274%27,m:83.55155482815057,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:16.448445171849425,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:68.64353312302839,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:31.356466876971613,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

The reason why your function doesn't work is because a parameter pack is deduced greedily; meaning `Args... args` matches `0b10`, `0b01` *and* `static_cast<size_t>(0)`. Then because there is no argument matching the `size_t i` anymore, substitution fails and the only candidate left is the first version of `get_init_size()`, which of course also is not a match. It's always hard or impossible to have extra parameters after a parameter pack. You could move `size_t i` to the front though. Another approach is to not pass `i` as a parameter, but add `+ 1` to the return value instead:

```
template<typename Arg>
constexpr std::size_t get_init_size(Arg&&) {
    return 1;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
constexpr std::size_t get_init_size(T&&, Args&&... args) {
    return get_init_size(args...) + 1;
}
```

Comment: You right but I also interested why it doesn't work